# Web Audio - Automating Voice Enhancements

Tags: javascript, audio, filter, signal-processing, speech

Hopefully no sound engineers see this post or they'll be out for my blood.

So, company I work for provides messaging services for our clients to their customers.  The majority of what we do is SMS, but some of our clients still rely heavily on voice, especially if they have an older customer base.

So we already have a system in place where our client can login online, record some audio for a specific customer using the [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API), and we'll deliver it.  No issues there.  Problem is that some of our clients don't have the best microphones, so the audio quality & legibility can suffer greatly.

So what I would like to do is basically just give them a button they can click to apply some audio/voice enhancements that should hopefully improve the audio (there will be a playback option so they can decide if they want to keep the enhancements or use the original recording).

The issue there is of course I'm not giving this option to sound engineers, musicians, content creators, etc.  These are marketing directors, secretaries, office staff, customer service agents, etc, so giving them a full EQ and expecting they'll be happy with it, much less able to work it, is completely out of the questions.

So I'm looking for more or less a single button approach, which applies a predefined set of enhancements to the audio.  This is unfortunately made somewhat more difficult, as the Web Audio API does have it's own limitations on what effects it can apply to audio, so I wanted to see if anyone hear has experience with the API and suggestions on how we can use it to improve recorded speech.

I have been doing some research on general voice enhancements, and several of them have given different suggestions depending on whether the speaker is male or female, so I think that also asking if they're voice is High Range or Low Range is fair as well.

Appreciate any help anyone can provide!

Comment: You can try high pass filter which removes the background noise (as noise is mostly in low frequency band), lib. like [pizzicato](https://alemangui.github.io/pizzicato) might be helpful

Comment: @Viney do you have a reference suggesting noise is mostly in low frequency band? I expect a low-pass filter with cutoff around 4kHz to give better result for voice (although I usually use a more dynamic approach by estimating the spectrum in a relatively quiet portion of the audio).

Comment: May be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16949768/how-can-i-reduce-the-noise-of-a-microphone-input-with-the-web-audio-api) would help